# ещё раз про select

Tags: c++, c, сокет, select, ssh

Добрый день!
Третий день бадаюсь с функцией select.
Всё вроде бы понятно, но есть один момент, который хотелось бы уточнить.
Из мануалов ясно, для чего все параметры функций. Не понятно только назначение третьего.
В MSDN написано:

> An optional pointer to a set of sockets to be checked for writability.

Как сие понимать? Что сокет готов для записи?

И ещё вопрос, более конкретный.
Есть код:

```
#define BUFSIZE 32768
void dotransport(ptr_t ti) {
    LIBSSH2_CHANNEL* channel = NULL;
    SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    s32_t saddr_len = sizeof(saddr);
    s8_t buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
    str_t client_addr;
    s32_t client_port;
    s32_t result, nonblock = 0;

    for (;;) {
        memset(&saddr, 0, saddr_len);
        sock = accept(((transport_info_t*) ti)->socket, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr, (int*) &saddr_len);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            message_error("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
            ShowWindowsError(WSAGetLastError());
            return;
        } else {
            client_addr = inet_ntoa(saddr.sin_addr);
            client_port = ntohs(saddr.sin_port);
            message_info("Forwarding connection from %s:%d here to remote %s:%d\n", client_addr, client_port, a_remote_addr, a_remote_port);
            channel = libssh2_channel_direct_tcpip_ex(((transport_info_t*) ti)->session, a_remote_addr, a_remote_port, a_local_addr, a_local_port);
            if (!channel) {
                message_error("Could not open the direct-tcpip channel!\n");
                SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
            }

            libssh2_session_set_blocking(((transport_info_t*) ti)->session, 0);
            if (ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonblock)) {
                ShowWindowsError(WSAGetLastError());
                SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
            }

            for (;;) {
                fd_set fdr, fdw, fde;
                s32_t rlen, wr;
                FD_ZERO(&fdr);
                FD_ZERO(&fdw);
                FD_SET(sock, &fdr);
                FD_SET(sock, &fdw);
                Sleep(1); // почему без этого программа вываливается с ошибкой?
                result = select(0, &fdr, &fdw, NULL, NULL);
                if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    ShowWindowsError(WSAGetLastError());
                    SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
                } else if (result > 0) {
                    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fdr)) {
                        rlen = recv(sock, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
                        if (rlen == 0) {
                            message_status("The client at %s:%d has disconnected\n", client_addr, client_port);
                            SHUTDOWN(E_OK);
                        } else if (rlen == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                            ShowWindowsError(WSAGetLastError());
                            SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
                        } else {
                            for (wr = 0; wr < rlen; wr += result) {
                                result = libssh2_channel_write(channel, buf + wr, rlen - wr);

                                if (result == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN) {
                                    continue;
                                } else if (result < 0) {
                                    message_error("libssh2_channel_write() failed: %d\n", result);
                                    SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fdw)) {
                        for (;;) {
                            rlen = libssh2_channel_read(channel, buf, BUFSIZE);

                            if (rlen == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN) {
                                break;
                            } else if (rlen < 0) {
                                message_error("libssh2_channel_read() failed: %d", rlen);
                                SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
                            }

                            for (wr = 0; wr < rlen; wr += result) {
                                result = send(sock, buf + wr, rlen - wr, 0);

                                if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                                    ShowWindowsError(WSAGetLastError());
                                    SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
                                }
                            }

                            if (libssh2_channel_eof(channel)) {
                                message_status("The server at %s:%d has disconnected\n", a_remote_addr, a_remote_port);
                                SHUTDOWN(E_FAIL);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 shutdown:
        if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET) {
            shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
            closesocket(sock);
        }

        // без этого почему-то канал не создаётся повторно
        libssh2_session_set_blocking(((transport_info_t*) ti)->session, 1);

        if (channel) {
            libssh2_channel_close(channel);
            libssh2_channel_free(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

здесь я пытаюсь сделать проброс портов по ssh туннелю.
всё нормально работает (например можно подключится к удалённому ssh серверу), пока я не пытаюсь подключиться по к удалённому компу rdp.
если убрать sleep перед select, то программа вываливается с критической ошибкой. Собственно это основной мой вопрос.

И ещё. почему выполнение программы застревает на select если я не укажу ему третий аргумент (fdw)? ведь по сути он мне не нужен?

Comment: Забыл добавить! Вместо Sleep(1) может быть просто вывод чего либо в stdout. Так тоже будет работать О_о

Comment: **Как сие понимать? Что сокет готов для записи?** - да, именно так и понимать. Если у сокета буфер полный, то записать в него сложновато.

Answer (score 0):

Не странное, а описанное в документации

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx

> Note  When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as select with the
>   timeout parameter set to NULL, Winsock may need to wait for a network
>   event before the call can complete. Winsock performs an alertable wait
>   in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous
>   procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread. Issuing another
>   blocking Winsock call inside an APC that interrupted an ongoing
>   blocking Winsock call on the same thread will lead to undefined
>   behavior, and must never be attempted by Winsock clients.

Вы своим sleep давали паузу перед тем как слушать сокеты, видимо за это время что-то происходило с сокетами, и select благополучно вываливался из ожидания.

Все правильно, вы добавили определенный таймаут, и все заработало. В документации сказано, что select использует таймаут, переданный по указателю, для расчета ожидания, поэтому передавать таймаут точно нужно. Если передать NULL, то вываливание из select будет неопределено, и в общем случае может затянуться бесконечно.

Не забудьте модифицировать код таким образом, чтобы перезапускать select при истечении таймаута или при вываливании из ожидания раньше таймаута по сигналу.

Ядерные функции, особенно связанные с синхронизацией и передачей данных в/из ядра ОС, особенно капризны и имеют тонну нюансов использования. Будьте очень внимательны и читайте документацию полностью, а не только header функции.

Answer (score -1):

проблема решилась добавлением четвёртого и пятого аргументов в select.
странное поведение функции или я чего-то не понимаю?

**UPD**:
Поторопился радоваться. Функция на разных ОС ведёт себя по разному.
Проверял на Win7 и Win10. В десятке работает. В семёрке по прежнему вылетает с ошибкой. Пришлось всё таки добавить вызов usleep перед select.