# пожалуйста объясните поведение функции select (winsock)

Tags: сокет, select, winsock

Добрый день!
На свой [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601072/%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-select) я так и не получил ответа. Попробую ещё раз.
Функция select вызывается в цикле. И на разных операционных системах (в частности в Win7), случайным образом может вызвать исключение. Методом проб и ошибок, был придуман костыль в виде вызова Sleep(1) перед вызовом select(). В этом случае программа работает стабильно. Но костыль это не выход и хотелось бы понимать, почему так происходит. Возможно необходимо устанавливать какие-то параметры для сокета?

Ещё одно небольшое уточнение про то, что делает программа. По сути это ssh-туннель до удалённого сервиса. В этом конкретном случае, когда прога вылетает с критом я запускаю mstsc (RDP-клиент). Ошибка может выскакивает всегда после авторизации уже на rdp сервере, но не всегда сразу, иногда может успеть рабочий стол загрузится.

Буду признателен за любую информацию, которая поможет хотя бы приблизится к разгадке =)

Спасибо!

Comment: Какой тип сокетов вы используете? TCP и AF_NET?

Comment: По поводу Sleep у меня такие догадки: Windows многозадачная система, библиотека сокетов создаёт ещё один thread для работы с сокетами. Ф-ция sleep - даёт сигнал на переключение в другой thread, в котором библиотека socket успевает делать свои действия (в плоть до тех пор пока не вызовет API которая вызывает переключение в другой thread одна из которых Sleep, или пока система многозадачности не посчитает нужным переключить в другой thread).

Comment: Думаю, т.к. у вас возникают вопросы с select, попробуйте посмотреть на уже готовые библиотеки, в часности ftp протокол использует два сокета, клиентский и серверный. Посмотрите реализацию ftpd.c (как select использован) например тут https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/ftpd.tproj/ftpd.c

Comment: Возможно для select вам нужно создать thread, а вы работаете в single-thread.

Comment: По большому счёту второй поток мне не нужен, т.к. программа работает только для одного единственного клиента. Но на самом деле, у меня действительно используется второй поток. В первом работает сокет а второй следит за запущенной программой и ждёт её завершения, чтобы прекратить работу сокета. Думаю сдесь не в этом дело. Не вижу связи, да и глюк этот проявил себя ещё до того как я дописал второй поток.

Comment: Клиент один, но сколько у вас сокетов? Два? Один поток одному сокету, второй другому. На примере ftpd это видно.